# How to properly exclude dependencies from ASDoc?

Tags: ant, asdoc

I have read some questions on StackOverflow on how to exclude the dependencies when creating the asdoc from Ant, but it seems I may not get it right.

Here (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_9.html) it says to simply set the -exclude-dependencies argument to true or false, but I get an error. Below is the Ant output:

```
Generate ASDoc:
     [echo] --- Generate ASDoc ---
     [exec] Error: no default arguments are expected
     [exec] Use 'asdoc -help' for information about using the command line.
     [exec] Adobe ASDoc 
     [exec] Version 4.6.0 build 23201
     [exec] Copyright (c) 2004-2011 Adobe Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.
     [exec] Result: 1
```

Here is the Ant task:

```
<target name="Generate ASDoc">

    <echo>--- Generate ASDoc ---</echo>

    <!-- delete all files in the doc dir -->
    <delete 
        includeemptydirs="true"
        >
        <fileset 
            dir="${DOCS_TARGET_DIRECTORY}" 
            includes="**/*" 
        />
    </delete>

    <!-- create docs -->
    <exec executable="${ASDOC_DIRECTORY}" > 
        <arg line="-doc-sources '${SOURCE_DIRECTORY}' "/>
        <arg line="-exclude-dependencies true"/>
        <arg line="-output '${DOCS_TARGET_DIRECTORY}' "/>
        <arg line="-main-title 'Title' "/>
        <arg line="-window-title 'Title' "/>
    </exec>

    <!-- compress docs -->
    <antcall target="Compress ASDoc" description="Compress asdocs" />

</target>
```

I wonder if I may be using it wrong. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Adobe's [Using the ASDoc tool](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSd0ded3821e0d52fe1e63e3d11c2f44bc36-7ffa.html)

> Note: You cannot use exclude-dependencies with input class specified by the doc-sources option.